# How to find the sum (exactly) of a MacLaurin series expansion?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

I was given the following series expansion to sum exactly:

$1 - 3/2 + 9/6 - 27/120 + 81/5040 - \ldots$

And am completely stumped. As far as I can tell, it must be either a Cosine or Sine MacLaurin series. I am having trouble deciding which to use due to the switch between even/odd factorials in the denominator. I tried going with Cosine and plugging in “3”, which seemed to work for the numerator of all terms, but again I cannot find a general term for the denominator.

I have been working at this problem for days now so any help at all would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The numerators seem to be consecutive powers of $3$ and the denominators seem to be factorials, but the latter aren't quite consecutive.  So I'm not really sure what your "series expansion" amounts to.  You can say you were given a series to "sum exactly", but it isn't a MacLaurin series unless you have a variable appearing to distinct natural powers.

Answer (score 1):

$1!=1,~2!=2,~3!=6,~4!=24,~5!=120$, all these figures are always helpful, and yes, the above are something like $3^{n}$.

Note that $\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^{3}}{3!}+\dfrac{x^{5}}{5!}-\dfrac{x^{7}}{7!}+\cdots$, so $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1-\dfrac{x^{2}}{3!}+\dfrac{x^{4}}{5!}-\dfrac{x^{6}}{7!}+\cdots$, now plug in $x=\sqrt{3}$.

The tricky point is that, $\dfrac{9}{3!}-\dfrac{27}{5!}+\dfrac{81}{7!}+\cdots=-3\left(-\dfrac{3}{3!}+\dfrac{3^{2}}{5!}-\dfrac{3^{3}}{7!}+\cdots\right)$

Comment: How would you skip the 4! in this case? I can see that the series goes from 1!, 2!, 3!, 5!, 7!, ... And none of my ideas seem to match up. (n+1)! would yield 1!, 2!, 3!, 4!, 5!, and so on. I also thought of (2n)! but this yields 0! (or 1), 2!, 4!, 6!, and so on.

Comment: the square root of 3 is a great trick

Answer (score 1):

If I am extrapolating the general term correctly, it appears that $S=1-3/2+9/6 + \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{(-3)^n}{(2n-1)!}$. Assuming that is right, you can compute  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-3)^n}{(2n-1)!}$ as a Maclaurin series of some familiar function at some simple argument. With that in mind, you can compute that Maclaurin series and then relate it back to this one (by adding in your "weird" first three terms and subtracting off this series' first three terms).

Comment: You aren't extrapolating correctly. The third term in your expansion would be $-\frac{27}{24}\neq-\frac{27}{120}.$ I strongly suspect a mistake on the problem-maker's part.

Comment: @CameronBuie How about now?

Comment: I can't disprove your attempt, anymore. That said, a single data point is not remotely the best source from which to derive a pattern. The alternation could have as easily started at $\frac96.$